# Problema con rutas relativas

Tags: html, html5

He estado viendo que cuando en una ruta relativa se usa al inicio `/` o `./` se le indica al navegador que vaya a la carpeta raíz del proyecto y desde ahi siga lo que se indica en la ruta por ejemplo se tiene la siguiente estructura de un sitio web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo `pedido.html` quiero poner un enlace que me lleve al archivo `registro.html` que esta dentro de la supcarpeta **clientes**.

Entonces la ruta que tendría que especificar sería:

```
<a href="/tienda/clientes/registro.html">Ir a registro</a>
```

Y no funciona por que el navegador interpreta esa ruta como si estuviera completa partiendo desde la raiz del servidor, agregandole el protocolo y el nombre del servidor, ejemplo:

```
http://localhost/tienda/clientes/registro.html
```

Y lo mismo me pasa cuando trato de enlazar imagenes, videos, archivos css y js.

Ahora si a la ruta especificada en la etiqueta `<a>` le agrego al inicio `./` funciona bien:

```
<a href="./tienda/clientes/registro.html">Ir a registro</a>
```

Pero si intento hacer esto mismo con imagenes, videos, css y js no funciona ya que el navegador me esta interpretando una ruta erronea, por ejemplo en el archivo `pedido.html` quiero poner una imagen en lugar del texto **Ir a registro**:

```
<a href="./tienda/clientes/registro.html"><img src="./img/registro.jpg"></a>
```

La ruta que interpreta el navegador es esta:

```
http://localhost/Mi Proyecto/tienda/img/registro.jpg
```

Entonces cual es el problema, por que no me funcionan correctamente este tipo de rutas relativas??

Comment: Porque la ruta está mal. Al indicar `../` está retrocediendo un carpeta. Al indicar `../../` está retrocediendo dos carpetas. En tu caso, `pedido.html` y la carpeta clientes son hermanos. Entonces, no se debe retroceder nada, y el enlace debe ser: `clientes/registro.html`

Comment: La primera afirmación que haces es incorrecta, empezar una ruta con un '/' indica que es absoluta, pues empezara al inicio del sistema de archivos (root).
Una ruta relativa empieza directamente con el nombre del fichero o directorio, o con './' ya que el '.' indica el punto donde estas actualmente.
Por ejemplo, si desde index.html quierer ir a pedido.html, la ruta seria "tienda/pedido.html" o "./tienda/pedido.html"
'../' se usa para 'salir' del directorio actual, por ejemplo, si desde registro.html quieres ir a producto.html, la ruta relativa seria "../../productos/productos.html"

Comment: @ArnauCastellví esa afirmación no la digo yo, la dicen varias páginas y videos de youtube. Y ahi es donde viene la confunción

Comment: @JorgeAlonso Espero que se haya solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos.**

Básicamente hay dos formas de especificar [rutas de archivos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)): **Relativa** y **Absoluta**.

Al colocar únicamente `/` estás indicando ruta absoluta; esto acorde a la ruta raíz en el servidor; es decir los archivos que se encuentran conforme a la configuración que este establecida como la raíz.

Por otro lado `./` y `../` son rutas relativas; donde `./` implica a partir de donde está el archivo que se carga; mientras que `../` es nivel anterior a partir de donde esta el archivo que se carga. Estas son rutas relativas.

Te sugiero identifiques donde es tu raíz en el servidor; pues puede ser ese el detalle; prueba poniendo una imagen en lo que consideras raíz (digamos que la imagen se llama *paisaje.jpg*); y debe mostrarse en tu navegador con http://localhost/paisaje.jpg si hay error no se carga entonces donde lo colocaste no es la raíz de tu sitio.
Esto de forma normal; cosa a parte de configuración que requieras agregar/ajustar por Urls amigables...

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Puedes usar `../../` para indicar dos niveles arriba y así anidar `../` para indicar rutas relativas arriba tantas como desees, pero verifica no quieres ir "fuera" de niveles que te permite y/o dentro de tu sitio en el servidor web.

Answer (score 0):

## URI

Primero, los conceptos. Así que hablemos un poco de URI. Según la Wikipedia, [uri](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_de_recursos_uniforme) es:

> una cadena de caracteres que identifica los recursos –físicos o abstractos– de una red de forma unívoca.

Esto quiere decir que si conozco la URI, puedo obtener un recurso de la red (siempre que esté disponible).

Tiene la forma general:

[image: forma general de una URI]

Ejemplos de URI's comunes serían

| URI | Esquema | Anfitrión | ruta | consulta | fragmento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595974`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595974) | https | es.stackoverflow.com | /questions/595974 |  |  |
| https://www.google.com/search?q=ruta+relativa+y+absoluta | https | www.google.com | /search | q=ruta+relativa+y+absoluta |  |
| https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/absolute-and-relative-urls#relative-urls-as-command-text | https | learn.microsoft.com | /es-es/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/absolute-and-relative-urls |  | #relative-urls-as-command-text |

Al final, siempre que establecemos un hipervínculo, el sistema tiene que ser capaz de determinar la URI completa del recurso que estamos vinculando.

Sin embargo, tenemos la facilidad de escribir vínculos que no tienen toda la URI, sino solamente la ruta o parte de ella, consulta y fragmento (si aplican)

Por ello, ahora nos centraremos en la **ruta**, que es lo que nos interesa. De aquí en adelante, cuando diga ruta, podemos entender que a dicha ruta siempre se le puede agregar una consulta y fragmento. No lo menciono en cada caso para mantener el texto simple y más fácil de entender.

Solo tenemos a la hora de escribir la dirección de un hipervínculo, tenemos la opción de:

- Escribir toda la URI del recurso que queremos enlazar, por ejemplo `<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>`
- Escribir solamente la ruta. En este caso, el sistema utilizará el mismo esquema, usuario, anfitrión y puerto del recurso actual, es decir, el que contiene el vínculo. Así, si estoy dentro de esta pregunta `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595974/problema-con-rutas-relativas`, se entenderá que un vínculo que contenga una ruta, estará dentro de `https://es.stackoverflow.com` y el sistema utilizará esta información para construir la URI completa. La ruta se construye generalmente con una simple concatenación. Dicho esto, la ruta puede ser:

  - Absoluta: Se entiende por ruta absoluta toda ruta que comience por una `/`, que se considera la raíz del sistema. Así, si dentro de `http://miservidor.com/misistema/misubsistema/carpeta1/pagina.html`, las rutas estarán dentro de `http://miservidor.com`. Por ejemplo, si escribo un vínculo así: `<a href="/clientes/alta.php">Alta de clientes</a>`, al hacer clic el sistema navegará a: `http://miservidor.com/clientes/alta.php`.
  - Relativa: Es toda ruta que no comienza por `/`. Estas rutas se considerarán relativas a la ruta del recurso actual. Es decir, si me encuentro dentro de `http://miservidor.com/misistema/misubsistema/carpeta1/pagina.html`, las rutas serán relativas a `http://miservidor.com/misistema/misubsistema/carpeta1/`. Así, si escribo `<a href="clientes/alta.php">Alta de clientes</a>`, el sistema navegará a: `http://miservidor.com/misistema/misubsistema/carpeta1/clientes/alta.php`

    Como puedes observar, no hace falta que la ruta relativa comience con `./`, basta con que no comience con `/`.

    El sistema web, en este punto, replica lo que es común en sistemas de archivos con rutas jerárquicas, que es que hay dos *carpetas especiales* dentro de cada *carpeta*. Estas son:

    - `.` que es el directorio actual
    - `..` que es el directorio superior

    Esto es útil cuando quieres construir rutas relativas a recursos que están en carpetas superiores o del mismo nivel de la carpeta actual, siguiendo el ejemplo anterior, si escribimos el siguiente vínculo: `<a href="../clientes/alta.php">Alta de clientes</a>` el sistema navegará a `http://miservidor.com/misistema/misubsistema/clientes/alta.php`.  Es decir, primero subirá un nivel, de la carpeta `/misistema/misubsistema/carpeta1` a `/misistema/misubsistema`.

    Puedo subir cuantos niveles quiera, siempre y cuando haya suficientes niveles en la carpeta actual: `<a href="../../../clientes/alta.php">Alta de clientes</a>` subirá 3 niveles y navegará a: `http://miservidor.com/clientes/alta.php`

## Tu caso

En el sistema de rutas relativas, no hay nada que indique que vaya a la raíz de un proyecto. De hecho, no existe el concepto de proyecto, sistema o sub-sistema, como tal.

Así, `/` es una ruta absoluta a todo el dominio, y `./` es una ruta relativa a la carpeta actual.

Viendo tu caso en particular, entiendo que a lo que le llamas **raíz** es la raíz de tu proyecto, pero no estará necesariamente en la raíz del dominio. Esto es común en muchos sistemas.

Digamos que yo tengo un sistema de blogs, y en un servidor estará instalado directamente en la raíz: `miblog.com/` mientras que en otros podría estar en alguna carpeta o sub-carpeta, por ejemplo `miempresa.com/blog/` o `miasociacion.org/guatemala/blog/`.

Así, no puedes usar rutas absolutas directamente en los enlaces para ir directamente a recursos de tu proyecto o sistema. Necesitas o bien conocer la ruta raíz de tu proyecto y concatenarla o construir siempre rutas relativas a los recursos.

Si usas algún lenguaje de programación, podrías tener una variable que tenga la parte `/guatemala/blog/` e ir concatenando a esta rutas *absolutas* desde la raíz de tu proyecto.

Pero si tienes solo HTML, no puedes hacer esto. Sin embargo, si puedes enlazar cualquier recurso dentro de tu proyecto, solo que solo puedes utilizar rutas relativas a la carpeta del recurso actual, que es el recurso en el que lo estás vinculando.

En el caso concreto que estás en `tienda/pedido.html`, puedes enlazar la página de registro con la ruta relativa `clientes/registro.html` que se convertirá en `tienda/clientes/registro.html`.

Observa cómo he tenido el cuidado de no iniciar las rutas con `/`, pues estas son relativas a la raíz de este sistema, que bien podría ser `http://localhost/Mi Proyecto/`

Si quisieras enlazar la página de productos desde la de pedidos, la ruta sería: `../productos/producto.html`.